# ImportError No module named utils

Tags: raspbian, python, audio

I am trying to run a program in python on RaspberryPi from stackexchange but getting an error

```
ImportError: No module named utils
```

Can you please help me resolve this issue?

```
import pyaudio, wave, utils

BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
REC_SECONDS = 5
RATE = 44100
WAV_FILENAME = utils.generate_random_token()
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16

#init sound stream
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = pa.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    input = True,
    channels = 1,
    rate = RATE,
    input_device_index = 7,
    frames_per_buffer = BUFFER_SIZE
)

#run recording
print('Recording...')
data_frames = []
for f in range(0, RATE/BUFFER_SIZE * REC_SECONDS):
    data = stream.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
    data_frames.append(data)
print('Finished recording...')
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
pa.terminate()
```

Comment: Doesn't the post you copied the code from mention where to get utils?

Comment: Which version of python are you running this with?

Comment: @SteveRobillard `python2.7`

Answer (score 4):

First install pip:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

then install the utils module using pip:

```
pip install utils
```

If you get an error about permissions use sudo and rerun the above command:

```
sudo pip install utils
```

if you get an error about the README.txt file:

switch to the **/build/utils** directory and create an empty **README.txt** file:

```
touch README.txt
```

then rerun the pip install command.

Comment: do i know where is this `/build/utils` folder

Comment: check your current folder. the full path I believe is included in the error message.